# Spring JPA provider produces wring exception on optimistic lock failure

Tags: spring, jpa

In case there is failure in optimistic locking I expect JPA entity manager to throw javax.persistence.OptimisticLockingException

Yet when I use spring orm jpa it provides ObjectOptimisticLockingException which is not related with expected one - so the question is,  WTF? Do I misunderstand JPA documentation,  or did the spring guys ignored standarts?

Most funny thing is that in JUnit  test case proper exception is thrown ( Wrapping StaleObjectException ),
while in web app it is FUBAR.  Spring configuration is reused  for unit test.

Here is some code for clarity :

```
<!-- JPA entity manager configuration -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="${database.testonborrow}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database.validationquery}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="provisioning"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.delimiter.type" value="InnoDB" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature. Spring's HibernateTemplate and its interceptors around repositories translate exceptions into Spring exceptions. The idea is that if you have a Hibernate-based DAO, an iBatis-based DAO or a JDBC-based DAO, they all throw the same types of exceptions, so that the client code doesn't have to care.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html#dao-exceptions

Comment: Funny part is that  I use JPA,  I get JPA entity manager  and would like to get JPA confirm exceptions. I'm perfectly aware that there is hibernate below the covers, but whole point of DI is to not to care about  JPA or even spring  in my code.